# Этимология выражения "хернёй страдать"

Tags: этимология

На другом форуме кто-то поделился следующим инсторическим толи анекдотом толи былью:

В XIX веке военнообязанные, но достаточно обеспеченные мещане косили от армии следующим образом: покупали у доктора справку о том, что они больны грыжей, и таким образом от армии отмазывались. Грыжа на используемом в медицинских документах Латинском языке называется "hernia", и, соответственно, у симулянтов в бумагах стоял диагноз "hernia", который для незнакомого с латынью обывателя читался как "херня". Соответственно и появилось выражение "хернёй страдать" как синоним "симулировать".

Так вот, любопытно узнать у знакомых с этимологией историков или филологов: это настоящая история или анекдот?

Comment: А незнакомый с латынью обыватель вообще латиницу-то мог прочесть?

Comment: @bipll Я латынь не знаю, но прочитать могу.

Comment: @bipll латынь в гимназиях с первого класса была, насколько мне известно. мы же тут говорим о "достаточно обеспеченных мещанах".
а, пардон, "незнакомый с латынью обыватель" в исходном тексте. ну, все это бросает сомнения, которых и так немало

Comment: я не филолог и не историк, но прокомментировать могу. тогда фразу `"х..нёй страдать"` нужно воспринимать как опошление оригинала, хотя мне кажется, что именно она является оригиналом, потому что `хер` - это как правило замена слову `х.й`. ну и вообще сначала стоило бы установить временные рамки возникновения этой фразы (лично мне она знакома только с 90-х века XX) и правдоподобность утверждения о том, что в XIX в. от армии косили и именно таким способом

Comment: Google Translate подтверждает происхождение, приведённое в анекдоте (https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru&eotf=0&sl=la&tl=ru&q=hernia).

Comment: @Arhad вообще-то он подтверждает, что грыжа по-латыни hernia, что и так знают довольно многие, ибо по-английски она так тоже.

Comment: Само слово, даже как производное, не употребляется ни у Фасмера, ни у Даля, хотя глагол у Даля есть, следовательно, существительное более позднего происхождения. А уж с латынью --сказки.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, тут еще надо учитывать `хер` который буква, от которого (насколько мне известно) пошло слово "похерить"

Comment: @Alissa да, но в данном случае я своим субъективным взглядом не усмотрел связи с историческим так сказать, легитимным, `хером`

Answer (score 5):

Ну раз всамделишные филологи не спешат появиться...

Подозрительны:

- огласовка `h` как `[х]` в девятнадцатом веке;
- насколько мне известно, ни одного завалящего примера такого употребления, — при том, что какие-нибудь "ноги хером" до нас вполне себе дошли;
- то, что у экспрессивного и разговорного выражения так забылся первоначальный смысл; это не какое-нибудь "довлеть".

По последнему пункту можно предположить влияние "дурью маяться", но гораздо более вероятным кажется, что от "дурью маяться" оно на самом деле и произошло — видимо, как придуманный кем-то маньеризм. У `страдать` [той или иной]`-нёй`, особенно в матерном варианте, все задатки успешного речевого мема: смысл предельно ясен, а вот сочетание двух разных стилистических окрасок застает врасплох. Это фраза, которую хочется взять себе.

В русском просторечии много выражений, явственно возникших в какое-то конкретное время в конкретном месте, и хотя большинство из них старые — "кузькина мать", "как на Маланьину свадьбу", "куда Макар телят не гонял", есть, например, и вполне современное "е...ть ту Люсю". Здесь хотя и отсутствует имя собственное, но очень ощущается чья-то частная любовь к усложнению речи, а по времени появления фразы `страдать [...]нёй` можно предположить, что анонимный автор этой фразы с некоторой вероятностью еще жив.

Comment: Да, огласовка "h" в начале слова при переводе на русский может быть неоднозначной: иногда "г", иногда "х", иногда вообще не огласовывается, если читатель французский учил. Так можно доболтаться до предположения о том, что "ёрничать" из того же диагноза, только прочитанного на французский манер. :)

Comment: @Michael "Ёрничать" произошло от ярмарочных балаганов, где иногда показывался "Гамлет" с сильно искаженным сюжетом и обрусевшими именами. Поэтому Гамлет, держа в руках череп шута, произносил: "Бедный Ёрник! вот ты и доёрничался". Это я только что придумал, но не сомневаюсь, что изрядное число людей можно убедить в том, что все так и было.

Comment: Меня уже убедили. :-)

Насчет чтения Шекспира туземцам: если вы читаете по-английски полюбуйтесь вот на этот потрясающий рассказ о том, как антрополог пересказывала Гамлета бушменам и как они его поняли: 

https://law.ubalt.edu/downloads/law_downloads/IRC_Shakespeare_in_the_Bush.pdf

Comment: @Michael отлично, еще не дочитал, но эти местные деды мне нравятся ))